# How to prevent itemize from breaking page margins?

Tags: lists, margins

I'm using `\begin{itemize}` with some very long items, but they seem to ignore the standard page margins and give me bad box warnings. How do I prevent the list items from breaking from the margins of the page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Itemize should produce relatively normal paragraphs.  Something else is probably responsible.